# What happens in this If-Else in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, if-statement

I am having this if-else clause in haskell.

```
let f x y = if y/=0 then f (x+1) (y-1) else x in f 3 5
```

The result is 8. I can't understand why.

Can somebody explain it to me STEP-By-STEP?
Thanks for help!

Comment: @larsmans What input do you mean? `f` is called with x = 3 and y = 5

Comment: Just take a pen and paper, write down the initial call, and write down the recursive calls (this function just adds its arguments by subtracting 1 from y and adding 1 from x as long as y is greater than 0)

Comment: In case you got confused by `y/=0`. `/=` it's just inequality operator. So in c-like language `y /= 0` would be `y != 0`. Or maybe `!y`. And function `f x y` is just `x + y` with only restriction - if y < 0 then execution will never end.

Comment: An `if` in functional or logic programming?!

Comment: @d12frosted for *some* values of never :)

Comment: @CommuSoft well, it's actually `if-then-else`, not just `if`. And anyway all guards and other things can be written in terms of `if-then-else`. If you want your language to be complete you need `if-then-else`. Well, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @d12frosted: You mean Turing-complete? And yes, they can be rewritten. But some people argue that if you need an inline `if-then-else` instead of using a guard, your program is not functional enough (in that case one uses Haskell in the imperative way).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, so let's first make the function definition a bit more clear by using indentation

```
let f x y =
     if y/=0
         then f (x+1) (y-1)
         else x
in f 3 5
```

So f is called with arguments `3` and `5` at first. `y` being 5 (i.e. not 0), the `then` branch is executed, which calls f with arguments `4` and `4`. Since `y` is still not equal to 0, we go into the `then` branch again and call f with arguments `5` and `3`. This goes on until we finally call f with `x = 8` and `y = 0`. We then go into the conditional's `else` branch, which just returns `x`, i.e. 8.

Here is one way the expression `f 3 5` could be reduced:

```
f 3 5 -- y /= 0, so we go into the then branch
=> f (3 + 1) (5 - 1)
=> f 4 4 -- then branch again
=> f (4 + 1) (4 - 1)
=> f 5 3
=> f (5 + 1) (3 - 1)
=> f 6 2
=> f (6 + 1) (2 - 1)
=> f 7 1
=> f (7 + 1) (1 - 1)
=> f 8 0 -- this time we go into the else branch
=> 8
```

Comment: Great answer! Perhaps one could add the solution using guards? After all `if`s are (according to many) imperative statements, functional programs should not use them.

Comment: @CommuSoft, there's nothing imperative about `if/else`, it's the standard `Bool` eliminator.  `if` without an `else` clause is usually imperative.  Haskell programs tend not to use `if` much, but I think that's more stylistic than about functional/imperative.

Comment: @luqui: Well some programmers argue there are better systems builtin in such languages like guards and unification.

Comment: @CommuSoft `if` is just a syntax sugar of total guard over `Bool`. The "else" part is crucial here.